# web3 auth integration to Login page

Tags: javascript, react-native, blockchain, web3js, solana

I'm making a login page for my dapp, and I think I will build on Solana chain.

And I wonder how I can add web3.auth in the page.

I'm using **react-native**, not sure what to do with this step
[web3.auth quick start](https://web3auth.io/docs/quick-start?product=Plug%20and%20Play&sdk=Plug%20and%20Play%20React%20Native%20SDK&platform=React%20Native%20Bare):

```
await web3auth.login({
  loginProvider: LoginProvider.GOOGLE,
  redirectUrl: resolvedRedirectUrl,
});
```